# Conversion of Matlab Code to Java Program

Tags: java, android, matlab, cloud

How can I convert a Matlab Digital Image Processing code to a java program so that I can integrate it in an app? Also can I integrate a trained Machine learning module in the mobile app itself instead of processing it each time in the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

Windows, Linux, Mac:
[You can create a Java Package with MATLAB Code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler_sdk/gs/create-a-java-application-with-matlab-code.html)

Android:
You can [export Matlab code as C for Android then call from JNI](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWnadVCwMJw)

If you have only an ML model than the simplest way is to export weights and run on mobile optimized frameworks like [Tensorlfow Lite](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/) or [Tensorlfow](https://www.tensorflow.org/)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer.I'll definitely try doing this.